PDF of $z=\frac{AB-CD}{A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2}$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are independent Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$
I would like to find the PDF of the real random variable $$z=\frac{AB-CD}{A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2},$$ where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are independent Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
Alternatively, the problem can be seen as finding the PDF of $$z=\frac{\Re\{AB^*\}}{\vert A\vert^2+\vert B\vert^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\vert A+B\vert^2}{\vert A\vert^2+\vert B\vert^2}-1\right),$$ where $A$ and $B$ are independent circularly symmetric complex Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
After running a Monte Carlo simulation in Matlab, I believe $z$ is uniformly distributed in $[-1/2, 1/2]$, but I cannot prove it. Here is the Matlab code I used:
N = 1e6;
vars = randn(N,4);
z = nan(N,1);
for n = 1:N
    z(n) = (vars(n,1)*vars(n,2)-vars(n,3)*vars(n,4))/norm(vars(n,:))^2;
end

figure; cdfplot(z);
figure; histogram(z);

Any help will be much appreciated!

As $-D\sim D$, we have
$$Z=\frac{AB-CD}{A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2} \sim W=\frac{AB+CD}{A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2}.$$
It is enough to show that $W+\frac12\sim \mathcal U (0,1)$. We can write
$$W+\frac12=\frac{(A+B)^2+(C+D)^2}{(A+B)^2+(C+D)^2+(A-B)^2+(C-D)^2}$$
where all $A+B$, $A-B$, $C+D$, $C-B$ are independent and identically distributed, following $\mathcal N(0,2)$, using the characterization of the sum of and difference of two normal distributions [1]. Hence, by noting that the distribution of the sum of two squared independent standard normal random variables is $\text{Gamma}\left (1,\frac{1}{2} \right)$, we have
$$W+\frac12 \sim \frac{T_1}{T_1+T_2} \sim \text{Beta}(1,1) \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$$
where $$\small T_1=\frac{(A+B)^2+(C+D)^2}{2}$$ $$ \small T_2= \frac{(A-B)^2+(C-D)^2}{2}$$ are independent and have  $\text{Gamma}\left (1,\frac{1}{2} \right)$ distribution, and where the relation between Gamma and Beta distributions [2] is used.

(+1) This is amazing!

@SangchulLee Thanks for your kind words!

The following relies on 3 basic results regarding $\chi^2$ distribution and quadratic forms:

If $x\sim \mathrm{MVN}(0,I)$, then for symmetric matrix $A$,  $x'Ax$ is $\chi^2$ distributed iff $A$ is idempotent, and the d.f. is the rank of $A$.
If $x\sim \mathrm{MVN}(0,I)$, then $x'Ax$ and $x'Bx$ are independent iff $AB=0$, for symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$.
If $x\sim \mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \theta)$ independent of $y\sim \mathrm{Gamma}(\beta, \theta)$, then $\frac{x}{x+y}$ is Beta$(\alpha,\beta)$ distributed.

Let $x\sim \mathrm{MVN}_4(0,I)$, and $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac12 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac12 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &-\frac12 \\
0 & 0 & -\frac12 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Then the quantity of interest is $$z=\frac{x'Mx}{x'x},$$ i.e., a ratio of two quadratic forms. The denominator is clearly $\chi^2_4$ distributed. But the numerator is not a $\chi^2$ distributed variable because $M$ is not idempotent. We can add $\frac12$ of the denominator to the numerator to make the numerator also a $\chi^2$. Namely,
$$
z+\frac12 = \frac{x'Mx+\frac12 x'x}{x'x}=\frac{x'Nx}{x'x}
$$ where
$$N=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac12 & \frac12 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac12 & \frac12 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac12 &-\frac12 \\
0 & 0 & -\frac12 & \frac12 \\\end{bmatrix},$$which is now idempotent with rank 2. So the numerator is $\chi^2_2$ distributed.
But $$
z+\frac12 =\frac{x'Nx}{x'Nx+x'(I-N)x}.
$$
Note that $I-N$ is also idempotent with rank 2 and $(I-N)N=0$. Thus the denominator is a sum of two independent $\chi^2_2$ variables, one of them being the numerator.
It follows that $z+\frac12$ has a $\text{Beta}\left(\frac22, \frac22\right)$ distribution, i.e., $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$, by standard Gamma vs Beta relationship and $\chi^2_\nu \stackrel{D}= \text{Gamma}\left(\frac{\nu}{2},2\right)$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent circularly symmetric gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and unit variance. In this paper, it is proved that the law of $Z = Y/X$ has the density of the form
$$ f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\pi(1 + |z|^2)^2}, \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}. $$
Now, let $X = A + iD$ and $Y = C + iB$ so that $A, B, C, D$ are IID standard normal variables and
$$ V
:= \frac{AB - CD}{A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + D^2}
= \frac{\operatorname{Im}(\overline{X}Y)}{|X|^2 + |Y|^2}
= \frac{\operatorname{Im}(Y/X)}{1 + |Y/X|^2}. $$
Then the moment-generating function of $V$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{\xi V}]
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \, \frac{r}{\pi(1 + r^2)^2} \exp\biggl( \xi \frac{r \sin \theta}{1 + r^2} \biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\psi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \, (\sin \psi)\exp\biggl( \frac{\xi}{2}\sin\theta\sin\psi \biggr) \tag{$r=\tan(\psi/2)$} \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\xi/2)^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\psi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \, (\sin\theta)^n (\sin\psi)^{n+1}.
\end{align*}
By using the symmetry of the sine function and the beta function identity (or by integration by parts combined with mathematical induction), it is not hard to check that
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\psi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \, (\sin\theta)^n (\sin\psi)^{n+1}
= \begin{cases}
\frac{4\pi}{n+1}, & \text{$n$ is even}, \\
0, & \text{$n$ is odd}.
\end{cases}$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{\xi V}]
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\xi/2)^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}
= \frac{\sin(\xi/2)}{\xi/2}
= \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{d}v \, e^{\xi v}.
\end{align*}
Therefore it follows that
$$ f_V(v) = \mathbf{1}_{[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]}(v), $$
or equivalently, the law of $V$ is the uniform distribution over $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$.

Okay, so there are a few key facts of note. Here, I assume the following:

$\newcommand{\N}{\operatorname{Normal}}
X \sim \N(\mu_X,\sigma_Y^2)$
$Y \sim \N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$
$N_i \sim \N(0,1)$ are independent

Then:

$\chi^2(k)$ is the sum of $k$-many squared independent standard normals, i.e. $\sum_1^k N_i^2 \sim \chi^2(k)$.

Consequently, $\displaystyle X^2/\sigma_X^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$

Meanwhile, $X+Y \sim \N(\mu_X + \mu_Y, \sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)$, and for any constant $\alpha$ we have $\alpha X \sim \N(\alpha \mu, \alpha^2 \sigma_X^2)$.

Also, $X/Y \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$ if $X,Y$ are i.i.d. standard normals too. (The usual shift-and-division, i.e. $$X \mapsto \frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X^2}$$ will achieve this.)

Also of note is the polarization identity,
$$
XY = \frac{(X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2}{4}
$$



This list of facts should be more than enough to derive the distribution, so I'll leave the details to you.

Consider $A + jB$ and $C + jD$ as two independent circularly symmetric complex Gaussian random variables, each with mean 0 and variance 1. This aligns with the second representation in the question.
The numerator $\Re\{AB\}$ follows a product distribution of two independent standard normal random variables. This results in a distribution that is symmetric around zero and has heavier tails than a Gaussian distribution.
The denominator $|A|^2 + |B|^2$ follows a chi-square distribution with 2 degrees of freedom, which is equivalent to an exponential distribution.
The exact PDF of $z$ can be expressed as:
$$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+z^2)}$$
See https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-Ratio-of-Two-Correlated-Complex-Gaussian-Li-He/4f47903ad12807f50688477bdc7a8451189e4662.
